# Does it exist an online map service that allows me to select what to view?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, openstreetmap

I want to take a screenshot of a map over a certain block in a European capital that should be "flat" and only list the street names on the surrounding streets, that is - no point of interests, labels, house numbers and similar.

I have looked at Google Maps (they offer something similar but it is only accessible in satellite view), Bing, OpenStreet Maps and https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/?lon=13.368594&lat=52.459748&zoom=10&num=2&mt0=osm-no-labels&mt1=mapnik&marker=

BBBike was quite close but the zoom level was too limited (basically I want the resulting image to be "laptop screen-sized").

Something in-between these two:

[image]

(this is the same area in two different formats side-by-side)

Back in the 00s when I had a CD with Route 66 I could do this. Route 66 allowed me to select what elements I wanted to see on the map. Just deselect labels and POIs and selects street names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Google Map Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)** and switch on & off a vastly large amount of overlay labels:

[image: 0]